# Date comparison code implementation in python (plus some general code optimization)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv, datetime

I'm a really rookie python(3.X) student.
I'm working on some simple script to training my skill.
In the last one, I'm printing out some results for my Blood Bowl 2 PC-game league thanks to an external site (mordreck.com/goblinspy/) who collects stas for me without I have to learn the game developer's API and makes them avaible for download like an sqlite database.
I use a really simple csv with this structure, where every row is a different toruanment/league I play:
Turnament name, torunament's sqlite db link.
And I also have this script that checks the csv, gather the sqlite link, download the DB, and check the league last results and some other info's (like the datetime the match ends), This is the script (I know, is really uncorrect, long and "basic" but I'm still learning how to improve my skills and makes better codes! Sorry!):

```
### IMPORT STATEMENT ###
import csv, sys, os, urllib.request, sqlite3, datetime, pandas, time
### VARIABLES ###
datapath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + ('\\data\\') #!!!HARDOCDED PATH!!!!
datafile = 'sqlcompetitions.csv' #!!!HARDOCDED PATH!!!!
### DEFINING FUNCTIONS ###
def sql_reader(db_file): #SIMPLY AN SQL READER
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return (conn)
    except: 
        print("Something goes wrong!")
        return None

def downloader(pathname, file): #READ THE CSV, AND DOWLOAD THE SQLITE DB FOR EVERY LINK IN ROW
    with open (pathname + file, newline='') as competitionscsv:
        next(competitionscsv)
        competitions = csv.reader(competitionscsv, delimiter=',')
        for row in competitions:
            filename = pathname + row[0]
            print('collecting data from %s \n' % row[0])
            sqlfile = urllib.request.urlretrieve(row[1], filename +'.sqlite')
            print ('data collected for season: '+ row[0] + '!\n')

def extract_matches(path): #READ EVERY .SQLITE file in the folder and extract values I'm looking for
    for files in os.listdir(path):
        if files.endswith('.sqlite'):
            db = sql_reader(path + files)
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT finished, tvhome, idracehome, coachhome, teamhome, scorehome, tvaway, idraceaway, coachaway, teamaway, scoreaway FROM leaguematches")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print("DATA: %s; TVHOME: %s; IDRACEHOME: %s; COACHHOME: %s; TEAMHOME: %s; SCOREHOME: %s; TVAWAY: %s; IDRACEAWAY: %s; COACHAWAY: %s; TEAMAWAY: %s; SCOREAWAY: %s;\n" % row)
                time.sleep(1)

downloader(datapath, datafile)
extract_matches(datapath)
```

I know the datetime module basics, and want to implement my code adding the last date I use my script to checks results like a third value in every row of the csv, so when I checks for results again my script will compare it with the "finished" coloumn in DB's "Leguematches" table, and print only the new matches in the leagues from my last checks, and than overwrite the datetime in the csv with the last date gathered from the SQL DB. 
I know the script logic is a little bit Twisted, so before continue I'm here to ask what's the best logic way to procede and how to make my code more readable and logically correct... The only way I have in mynd at 3 AM is to make an empty global dictionary and when I read the csv joining it with {torunament name:datetime(my_csv_date)}, so I can reuse this dict into the extract_matches function... Any better Idea?
Thanks in advice, regards, and sorry for the very noob questions!!!
PS SOrry for my uncorrect English too...Hoping you'll understand me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the table so that the column takes the current time as the default value and simply not supply a value for the column.

e.g.

```
    CREATE TABLE log2 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp INTEGER DEFAULT (DATETIME('NOW')) )
```

Adding some rows would result in :-

[image]

***Note! there could be issues if the above (simplified for illustrative purposes) were used as you'd want to insert but with no columns/values specified.***

Comment: so You suggest to work directly in the .sqlite unless the .csv files? I think this doesn't works with my script, because every time i use it it will overwrite de .sqlite file...Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends upon how you use the above. In short SQLite is just a glorified file but getting the little bits is far more flexible.Basically you want to store the last used/run date, so why use two systems to do that. Such an exception would be [here - Updating a prepopulated database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103235/updating-a-prepopulated-database)

Comment: @HellSider probably a better answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternately try the following which needs no separate date holder as it uses the last date stored in the recipient database.

```
INSERT INTO leaugematches 
    SELECT null, tvhome, idracehome, coachhome, teamhome, scorehome, tvaway, idraceaway, coachaway, teamaway, scoreaway, finished 
    FROM lmdownload 
    WHERE finished > 
        (SELECT finished 
            FROM leaugematches 
            ORDER BY finished DESC LIMIT 1
        )
```

- **lmdownload** is the downloaded matches table.
- **leaugematches** is the App's matches table.

  - lmdownload and leaguematches tables are identical structure wise
- This SQL will **INSERT** rows into the **leaugematches** table using a [SELECT INSERT as per 2-INSERT INTO table SELECT ...;](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) .
- The data is extracted/copied from the rows returned from the SELECT statement.
- All the columns copy the data from the like-named column. However null is used for the **_id** column (an alias of the rowid column) [more about this here -SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  and [also here - Rowid Tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).
- The WHERE clause for the SELECT is what does the date checking.

  - It is saying only get rows (from the lmdownload table) WHERE the finished column is greater than the greatest finished date (ORDER BY finished DESC LIMIT 1) in the leaguematches table.
- The format of the **finished** column is important in that is must be sortable.

#### Example

The initial **leaguematches** table :-

[image]

The **lmdownload** table (with rouge entry, as highlighted) :-

[image]

The **leaguematches** table after the INSERT (run twice):-

[image]

- The rouge entry was not added because the finished date was not greater than the greatest finish date already in the leaugematches table.
- Accidental (on purpose for testing) 2nd run didn't duplicate rows again because of using the greatest date stored for the WHERE clause.

#### Example 2 More Data (with rouge entries, as highlighted) :-

[image]

The **leaguematches** table after the 2nd download data INSERT :-

[image]

- Again rouge entries not inserted

Comment: Ok I'm getting in! Really thank you! I've to modify a lot the script bt, while I'm working with sqlite, best to work with it in the strong way! Is really a great explaination, my datestamp have Hour/minutes too but I don't think it will cause some problem... sorry  for the late answer, I'm writing from Italy, so I'm Just waked-up! Really thank you again!!!! @MikeT